# Erro ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE ao enviar dados via 'POST' para servidor local

Tags: javascript, post

Até o dia de ontem estava tudo certo, mas depois de limpar o cache do navegador, por mais estranho que pareça, não consigo mais enviar dados via post para o servidor local, o GET funciona sem problema mas o Post não é enviado, a página fica carregando até cair e mostrar essa mensagem (em PTBR): "Esta página não está funcionando Nenhum dado foi enviado por localhost ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Obs: Na configuração de LAN, já desmarquei a opção de usar um servidor de proxy para a rede local como sugerido em outros posts mas não adiantou. Já testei com outros navegadores e é a mesma coisa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, faltou adicionar isso:

```
 let contentType = req.headers["content-type"];
```

no app.use